# Monodromy of the Gauss hypergeometric equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, reference-request, special-functions, hypergeometric-function

I'm looking for references where the construction of the monodromy of the Gauss hypergeometric equation is well explained.

Comment: This paper looks nice : http://pages.uoregon.edu/njp/beukers.pdf

Comment: @ N.H. that's a good reference, but the author, when he talks about eigenvalues, p.25, does not explain how he obtains them. Also, he does not mention the branch cuts. For me that's not clear.